# Navbar text center with .justify-content-center:

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

why when i add the class justify-content-center in my Navbar in Bootstrap the text remain on the left position?

[image: HTML Code]

I have find a instruction on the Docs of Boostrap where after the adding of this class the text of a Navbar will be centered.

[image: Docs]

Thank's for help.
Regards

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), showcasing the code **itself**, rather than an image containing it. Being able to copy the code helps us debug it much faster. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge not sure if it's useful to edit and show the image ... we need to have the code not image of code

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `<ul class="**navbar-nav** justify-content-center">` to `<ul class="**nav** justify-content-center">`. If keeping the `.navbar-nav` class is essential you will need to override the default styles for it doing something like:

`.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}`

Be aware you may need to adjust child element properties too. The easiest fix would be to simply remove `navbar-`

Quick pin here: https://codepen.io/jessburnett1980/pen/pVLQKO